# Proving a certain function is radial

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I want to prove that the function $J(y) = \int_{S^{n-1}} e^{i x \cdot y}  d\sigma_{n-1}(x)$ is radial (i.e. $J(y) = j(|y|)$ for some $j$) where $\sigma_{n-1}$ is the surface measure on the unit sphere in n dimensions $S^{n-1}$.  I've been working on this for a good while, but I can't figure out how I should do this.  I'm working from Folland, so I only have the above definition of radial to work from.

As we have for any (Borel, Lebesgue) measurable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, if $f \in L^+$ or $L^1$ then
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{S_{n-1}}f(rx')r^{n-1}d\sigma(x')dr $$

where $r = |x|$ and $x' = x/|x|$, I thought I could make use of the fact that $r=1$ to rewrite $J(y)$ into an integral over $\mathbb{R^n}$, but I can't get much further than that.  Any help is appreciated.

Note: the original problem just has $xy$ in the definition of $J(y)$, but I'm assuming that it's taking the inner product.

Comment: Since $\sigma_{n-1}$ is rotation invariant, you can make the change of variable $t=Rx$, which shows that $J(R^ty)=J(y)$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Rotation invariance of $\sigma_{n-1}$ would indeed be the best way of going about it, but I was wondering if there was a more direct method as the only definition of radial I've been given was that $F(x)$ is radial if $F(x) = f(|x|)$.  If not, I'll go down that route - thanks.

Comment: That condition is equivalent to $F(Rx)=F(x)$ for all rotations (easy exercise).